# Update query based on two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following table based on this query:

```
SELECT
    repName.repID, repName.Rep_Name, repName.Job_Code, GenItems.Item_Name,
    repName.Entered
FROM
    GenItems
    INNER JOIN repName
        ON GenItems.Job_Code = repName.Job_Code
ORDER BY
    repName.Rep_Name
```

I want to add an update routine to it. I want to update the entered field if the user entry matches the rep.ID and the Item Name. and finally return the Max value for the Entered field. Can I add this to this query or is it better to write another.

I just started working with sql, so if my questions seems basic, please forgive me. I am self taught and stumbling greatly.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want the entered field to be updated to?

Comment: What database system are you using? What version?

Comment: @aledpardo I am using sqlCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand fully your question.

You are showing us a SELECT statement. It can only be used to return a table-like result. If you want to upate a table you must use an UPDATE query. For the SQL-Server (and SQL CE) the query looks like this:

```
UPDATE repName
SET repName.Entered = x
FROM
    GenItems
    INNER JOIN repName
        ON GenItems.Job_Code = repName.Job_Code
WHERE
    repName.repID = x AND GenItems.Item_Name = 'y'
```

The difficulty is that tables have to be joined in the UPDATE statement. This not supported in Oracle for instance, where you have to do it with sub-selects.

Comment: I used the select statement because my data is on those2 tables. The repname table has all of my employees names, and the items table has the items they are responsible for. So I wanted to link both tables so that I only have to enter employee and item names once when adding them to the database.

Comment: Since there is a 1 to n relationship between employees and items, entering both at the same time is hardly possible. An application would typically show a list of employees. The user could select one employee from the list and open it in a second form where there is an employee name field and a list of items.